# The attachment has "already been sent" or has "been already sent"?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-order, present-perfect

- The  attachment has already been sent
- The  attachment has been already sent

While writing an email to my fiancé, I tried to convey that I had sent the referred attachment in a previous email. Which sentence is correct?

Is there an expression or phrase that means "a previous file attachment"?

Comment: This is easy to check online and in Word.,

Answer (score 1):

"The attachment has already been sent " is correct. You could also say simply "I have already sent the attachment".

Comment: I agree with your first sentence. However, your second is an ungrammatical mix of two sentences that say different things: if your point is your action, completed in the past, of sending, then "I sent the attachment" is OK but "already" doesn't fit; if your point is the present state of affairs that the attachment has been sent, then "I have already sent the attachment" is OK.

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct. There is no difference between the meaning of the two.

As a personal preference, I prefer:

> the attachment has already been sent

Over

> the attachment has been already sent

Because 'already' is a modifier. Consider: the job has almost been completed as oppose to the job almost has been completed, or the flight has always been delayed as oppose to the flight always has been delayed.

You can also substitute 'has been' with 'was' if referring to a past tense.

> the attachment was already sent

Over

> the attach already was sent

Comment: You could also say "the attachment has been sent already".

Comment: @Urbycoz You could also say "already the attachment has been sent", but doesn't sound as smooth.

Comment: In case you're wondering why you were downvoted (although I'm not the downvoter, so I don't know for sure), [see this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+already+been+made%2Chas+been+already+made&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20already%20been%20made%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20already%20made%3B%2Cc0). While "has been already sent" might have been grammatical 100 years ago, it no longer is used; *"has been already made"* currently occurs at 1–2% of the frequency of *"has already been made"*.